# NSManagedObjectContext - Child Context causing deadlock

Tags: core-data, concurrency, deadlock, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a parent - child - grandchild core data context setup in Core Data as below. Whenever I try execute a fetch request on the grandchild context, it causes a deadlock on the thread

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)defaultPrivateQueueContext
{
    if (!_defaultPrivateQueueContext) {
        _defaultPrivateQueueContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        _defaultPrivateQueueContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    return _defaultPrivateQueueContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainThreadContext {
    if (!_mainThreadContext) {
        _mainThreadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        _mainThreadContext.parentContext = [self defaultPrivateQueueContext];
    }
    return _mainThreadContext;
}

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)newPrivateQueueContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.parentContext = [[self sharedParliamentAPI] mainThreadContext];

    return context;
}
```

This is my code where it causes a deadlock (when trying to execute a fetch request):

```
- (void)fetchMenuItemsWithCompletion:(void (^) (BOOL success, NSString *message))completionBlock {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [APIHelper createNewRequestWithURLExtension:@"menuitems" httpMethodType:@"GET" parameters:nil];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfig];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSObject *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        if ([[json valueForKey:@"isSuccess"] boolValue]) {

            NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = self.defaultPrivateQueueContext;
            NSManagedObjectContext *privateQueueContext = [ParliamentAPI newPrivateQueueContext];

           [privateQueueContext performBlock:^{
                __block NSError *error;
                NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MenuItem"];
                NSArray *fetchedRecords = [privateQueueContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

                // do stuff with fetchedRecords

            }];
        } else {
            completionBlock([[json valueForKey:@"isSuccess"] boolValue], [json valueForKey:@"message"]);
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: What is using `mainThreadContext`? Is *everything* that uses that context doing so through performBlock or performBlockAndWait? If not, that can cause a deadlock in the child.

Comment: At the time that this code is executed, mainThreadContext is not being used. Yes, everything that uses that context is doing so through performBLock

Comment: If you set the root context as the parent of new child context, eliminating the main thread context, do you still deadlock?

Comment: The deadlock disappears when I set the parent of the new child context as the root context.

However, doing so this way will not update the mainThreadContext when changes are made (since it is a separate child of the root context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Core Data object structure looks like this:

[image]

Where you have a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context as the root context connected to the persistent store coordinator, which has a child `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` context, which in turn has a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context. This structure is recommended by a lot of people who write on The IntarWebs.

What is happening in your case is that the private queue context that is the main queue context is becoming busy, which is causing it's child to wait. Because the main queue context is using the main queue for all of it's work, it's not necessarily busy doing Core Data work when this happens (though this is still somewhat likely). The main queue does a lot of work other than Core Data, and all of those things will end up impacting the child any time it needs to communicate with the main queue context.

Additionally, a context created with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` is allowed to execute Core Data operations without explicitly using `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`.
For example, a main queue context can do this:

```
NSArray *results    = nil;
NSError *error      = nil;
results = [mainQueueContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

And is not *required* to do this:

```
[mainQueueContext performBlock:^{
    NSArray *results    = nil;
    NSError *error      = nil;
    results = [mainQueueContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
}];
```

The difference here is that the first example without the `performBlock:` will block the main thread waiting for the result. The second, using `performBlock:`, is asynchronous and will not block - the fetch request will be scheduled for execution on the queue. Obviously, the first example can cause some contention in any child contexts.

If your configuration had a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` context that was a child of another `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` context, that would be... bad. It's almost guaranteed to deadlock in that configuration. The good news is, you don't have *that* issue!

You can convert your code to using `performBlock:` with the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` context to mitigate this part of the problem. You can also use an `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` in place of your main queue context - there is not much of a good reason to use a main queue context at all. [NSFetchedResultsController can be used with a private queue context to do "background fetching"](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/93190211147/secrets-of-nsfetchedresultscontroller-happiness).

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer. I will try it out